# How to instantiate two generics classes which depends on each other?

Tags: swift, generics, nested-generics, protocol-oriented

I have two generic classes which need each other to instantiate, is there an elegant way of doing that? 
Check out the following example:

```
protocol Presentable {
    /// Protocol for view
}
protocol Action {
    /// Protocol for Presenter
}

class Presenter<T: Presentable> : Action {
    /// Presenter looking for a class that implementing the Presentable protocol
}

class SomeViewController<T: Action> : Presentable {
    /// SomeViewController looking for a class that implementing the Action protocol
}
```

As you can see, `SomeViewController` expecting the `Presenter` and the `Presenter` expecting the `SomeViewController`. 
So it's impossible to create one of them since we will have endless loop

```
let vc = SomeViewController<Presenter<SomeViewController<Presenter>>> ...
```

Is there an elegant way of solving it?